# Declare variable in ngFor

Tags: angular

in my angular2 project I need to present a matrix.
This is my current code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let worker of workers">
    <td class="{{worker.fired ? 'fired-worker':''}}">{{worker.lastName}}<br>{{worker.firstName}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let course of courses;" class="sk-table-sub-header">

        <div *ngIf="course.isGeneric">
            <div class="col-xs-6" sc-dc [sc-dc-date]="matrix[worker.id][course.id].expiration">
                <date-picker (onDateChanged)="onDateChanged($event, worker, course, 'genericStartDate')" [date]="matrix[worker.id][course.id].genericStartDate></date-picker>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 training-table-rounded-cell" sc-dc [sc-dc-date]="matrix[worker.id][course.id].expiration">
                <date-picker (onDateChanged)="onDateChanged($event, worker, course, 'expiration')" [date]="matrix[worker.id][course.id].expiration" ></date-picker>
            </div>                    
        </div>
        ...
```

As you can see I use `matrix[worker.id][course.id].expiration` multiple times.
I try to avoid that declaring a variable like this:

```
 <td *ngFor="let course of courses; let item = matrix[worker.id][course.id]" ...>
```

But I get a parse error:

```
 Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 44 in [ngFor let course of courses; let i = matrix[worker.id][course.id]] in TrainingPlanComponent@44:20 ("r.fired ? 'fired-worker':''}}">{{worker.lastName}}<br>{{worker.firstName}}</td>
```

Is there a way to achieve my intent?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently can't assign arbitrary values to template variables.

- template variables can refer to elements or components where they are added
- `exportAs` references can be assigned to template variables like `#xxx="ngForm"`
- local variables created by directives like `index` by `ngFor` can be assigned

There is an open issue to support your use case as well but it's unclear if and when this will be supported.

As a workaround you might consider wrapping a part of your template into its own component and pass values to `@Input()`s