# Unable to declare a variable within *ngFor angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, let, ngfor

I am trying to declare a variable of my own within `*ngFor` but it throws error and is not working.

I loop through a collection of `buttons`, and show icon whenever the condition inside `*ngIf` is satisfied.

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons;" type="button">
    <i *ngIf="button.icon || (button.conditional && button.iconConditional)" [attr.class]="button.icon"></i>
</button>
```

I want to reuse the condition within `*ngIf` to add a class conditionally to `<button>` as well.

When I try to do as below, it fails at "`let showIcon`".

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons; let showIcon = button.icon || (button.conditional && button.iconConditional)" type="button" [ngClass]="{'icon':showIcon}">
    <i *ngIf="showIcon" [attr.class]="button.icon"></i>
</button>
```

Can someone please help.

Even trying to add showIcon variable within ngFor throws me error as below:
[image: Error]

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Seems like it's imposible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114178/declare-variable-in-ngfor

Comment: There should be some way though :(

Comment: Am I the only new Angular user who is absolutely amazed by this? How on Earth are we supposed to do anything conditional inside a loop?